# Mongodb - Copy files for mongorestore

Tags: backup, mongodb

I've got 3 nodes in a replica set.

Each time when performing a `mongorestore` from the Master, the secondaires go into a `RECOVERING` state. The oplog cannot keep up. unfortunately I cannot increase the oplog size because lack of disk space.

Now, I want to perform a manual restore by copying the files. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/

Here is a snippet of the files which I got:

```
meee@mongo-p01:~$ sudo ls -la /var/lib/mongodb
[sudo] password for meee:
total 44052516
drwxr-x---   4 mongodb root          4096 Feb 22 17:54 .
drwxr-xr-x. 32 root    root          4096 Feb 23 01:59 ..
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb   67108864 Feb 22 17:54 mymongobase.0
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb  134217728 Feb 22 17:08 mymongobase.1
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:14 mymongobase.10
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:12 mymongobase.11
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:14 mymongobase.12
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:14 mymongobase.13
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:14 mymongobase.14
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:14 mymongobase.15
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:14 mymongobase.16
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:15 mymongobase.17
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:21 mymongobase.18
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:51 mymongobase.19
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb  268435456 Feb 22 17:08 mymongobase.2
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:51 mymongobase.20
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:54 mymongobase.21
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:54 mymongobase.22
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb  536870912 Feb 22 17:08 mymongobase.3
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 1073741824 Feb 22 17:08 mymongobase.4
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:11 mymongobase.5
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:53 mymongobase.6
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:54 mymongobase.7
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:54 mymongobase.8
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:53 mymongobase.9
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb   16777216 Feb 22 17:54 mymongobase.ns
drwxr-xr-x   2 mongodb mongodb         40 Feb 22 17:54 journal
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb   67108864 Feb 22 17:07 local.0
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:54 local.1
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb 2146435072 Feb 22 17:54 local.2
-rw-------   1 mongodb mongodb   16777216 Feb 22 17:54 local.ns
-rwxr-xr-x   1 mongodb mongodb          6 Feb 22 17:06 mongod.lock
drwxr-xr-x   2 mongodb mongodb          6 Feb 22 17:54 _tmp
```

What are the correct steps I should take?

- 1. Reset all mongos by reïnstalling
- 2. Perform a mongorestore on the master
- 3. Right after the restore, stop all mongod
- 4. Copy all local.x and mymongobase.x files to other nodes
- 5. Start mongod on all nodes?

I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ensure you have enough disk space!
- Shutdown mongos on all 3 nodes
- From Master node; tar all local* and mymongobase* files
- SCP files to 2 secondaries
- Unpack files in mongo data location (/var/lib/mongodb)
- Start mongod on all nodes

Works for me